# "Property theme does not exist on class ..." with Styled Component themes?

Tags: typescript, sass, styled-components

Here is my index.tsx:

```
const theme = require('sass-extract-loader?{"plugins": ["sass-extract-js"]}!./parameters.scss');

...

<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <ScrollToTop>
                <App />
            </ScrollToTop>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Here is my styled component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

interface FlexContainerProps {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    children: any;
}

export default function FlexContainer(props: FlexContainerProps) {
    const Container = styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        @media all and (min-width: ${props.theme.minWidthLargeDevice}) {
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    `;
    return (
        <Container>
            {props.children}
        </Container>
    );
}
```

I get the error

```
Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'FlexContainerProps'.
```

Why is theme not available to my component? How can I get rid of this error?

I am using styled components v4.